# Javax.servlet dependency does not work

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

**I am creating a Gradle project in Intellij to improve my skills because I am learning. Previously, I created the same project with Maven and It is working well.**

My project is this:
[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5MT6.png)

How you can see in the image "**HttpServlet**" is not recognised and I don't know why because I have the dependency and apparently everything is correct, here is my **build.gradle** with the dependency:

```
group 'com.aprendiendo.java'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
}
```

In the first image It can be seen how in the **Gadle Project menu** -> **Dependences folder** is javax.servlet.... but however It does not work because I can't use anything of Java Servlet API (Classes, etc...), how you can see in the image of my project which I put before.

I have revised everything and I dont know what is happening.

Comment: What means ` It does not work.`?

Comment: It means that the dependency is in the code but it doesn't matter because I can´t use the classes of the library...in this case HttpServlet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a similar setup on my IntelliJ version and everything actually ended up working ok.  You can try NOT using the fully qualified name in the extension.  Use

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet
```

instead of

```
public class Servlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
```

Then hover over HttpServlet with your mouse and see if IntelliJ autosuggest an import.  If it does then you can then use Alt + Enter to complete the import.  This may juice IntelliJ to recognize the dependency.  You can also try Build --> Make Project to see if recognizes.

You may also want to check under File --> Project Structure and select the libraries node.  Look and see if the dependencies are listed: javax:servlet-api:3.1.0, junit:junit:4.11, org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3.

I did only test this on a later version of IntelliJ 2016, but it should work.  Feel free to post back comments/questions.

Comment: Thanks M.Rizzo. I did everything which you said me and there are only one of the suggestions which I haven't tried and I tried to do it but I can't: -**You may also want to check under File --> Project Structure and select the libraries node. Look and see if the dependencies are listed: javax:servlet-api:3.1.0, junit:junit:4.11, org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3.** when I go to file->project structure->libraries there aren't anything and I don't know why or what I have to do, I'm trying add them with the plus button but I don't find where are they.

Comment: Ty M.Rizzo Finally, thanks to this answer ** I did only test this on a later version of IntelliJ 2016, but it should work. Feel free to post back comments/questions.** I decided update my Intellij and now everything is ok -_- omg!! two days with this problem and update the IDE was the solution ... no comments xD